# NullPointerException: two collections and a for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, collections, nullpointerexception, nested-loops

In another method (ALGO_1) I search over elements of `<background>` and check the value H_NAME equals a value entered in the main. When I attempt to run the code, I get a null pointer exception. Upon trying to print (with `System.out.println` etc) the H_NAME value after each for loop in the snippet, I also get a null statement returned to me.

I am fairly certain that the collection is simply not storing the data gathered up by the Scanner. But when I check the collection size with `size()`, it is about the right size.

Main questions are:

- from the readBackground method is the data.add in the wrong place?
- is the snippet simply structured wrongly?

When I use `System.out.println` to check the Background object values name, start time, increment, etc., they print out fine.

```
for (Hydro hd: hydros) {        
    System.out.println(hd.H_NAME);  
    for (Background back : backgs) {  
        System.out.println(back.H_NAME);  
        if (back.H_NAME.equals(hydroName)) { //get error here  

            public static Collection<Background> readBackground(String url) throws IOException {

                URL u = new URL(url);
                InputStream is = u.openStream();  
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);  
                BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(isr);  
                String line ="";  
                Vector<Background> data = new Vector<Background>();  
                while ((line = b.readLine())!= null) {  
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(line);  
                    String name = s.next();  
                    double starttime = Double.parseDouble(s.next());  
                    double increment = Double.parseDouble(s.next());  
                    double sum = 0;  
                    double p = 0;  
                    double nterms = 0;  
                    while ((s.hasNextDouble())) {  
                        p = Double.parseDouble(s.next());  
                        nterms++;  
                        sum += p;  
                    }  
                    double pbmean = sum/nterms;  
                    Background SAMP = new Background(name, starttime, increment, pbmean);  
                    data.add(SAMP);  
                }  
                return data;  
            }
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you might want to try formatting the code so it's a little more readable.  You also might consider letting us see the rest of it because there must be some stuff missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a NullPointerException (NPE) when you call `back.H_NAME.equals(xxx)`, it probably means either `back` is null or `back.H_NAME` is null.

You say that when you print `back.H_NAME`, you get null, so that suggests that `back.H_NAME` is actually null. You haven't shown us any code that describes the class `Background`, so it's hard to give you any more help.

Comment: True I thought I may have missed something. Here's the code for Background. Thanks.

Public class Background {  

 String H_NAME;  
 double T_START;  
 double DT; 
 double PBMEAN;  
 
 
 
 public Background(String name, double starttime, double   increment, double pbmean) { 
 
 name = H_NAME;  
 starttime = T_START;  
 increment = DT;  
 pbmean = PBMEAN;  
  
 }  

}

Comment: Yeah, I think its definitely null by the time I get to the method checking the H_NAME variable, I just cant work out why. Since if I print out the steps of the method that creates <background> the data is definitely being read...